# identify Photoshop action - GTA style - could anyone direct me to this, or something similar to it?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

So basically I used this action in the past, a good while ago my photoshop reset and I never thought to look for the action again, and now I'd really like to have it ... I thought it existed as a 'Grand theft auto style' but any action I find online called this, doesn't seem to be the right one .. (the pic with the action on it is below)

[image]

could anyone direct me somewhere to download this action or something very similar to this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an action for something as simple as this.  Many Photoshop actions are simply a combination of several filters applied to different layers, and your example is no exception.

Here's an example:

Duplicate the image layer. Then use the Cutout filter on Layer 1, and the Watercolour filter on Layer 2, and change the blending mode to "Lighter Colour".  If the texture is too heavy, reduce the opacity of the top layer a little.

[image]

Comment: Tested this out on the same picture and got pretty much the same outcome, Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like Posterize

Image > Adjustments >Posterize…

[image]

[image]

Comment: its definitely a specific action online that may resemble a posterize effect - however photoshops own posterize feature tends to produce poorer colours and also makes the image much more grainy than the action I had used